Sun protection while establishing Camellia Sinensis (tea plants)
I live in rural Auckland, New Zealand (Microclimate probably zone 9B equivalent ?).   Summers days get to 25-29c, with very high UV (10-11 on sunny days) due to proximity to thinness of Ozone round the Ozone hole.    We are at the height of summer and days are about 16 hours long.
I have planted some Camellia sinensis sinensis on the South East side of my house - which still seem to be getting a lot of sun.   Plants are small - 50-60cm high above the ground, many with only leaves coming off the vertical stem - so not at all bushy.  Plants are about 50cm apart in the hope it will form a hedge. At a guess the plants will be exposed to more then 6 hours full sun many days.
I'm wondering if it is wise to up shade cloth temporarily  (eg from now until mid Autumn) to the North East (remember, Southern Hemisphere) to partly shade the plants from the long sun duration while they get established, or if I can simply water the plants more often.     I do comment that long term, Shade Cloth is not an option as this is at the entry to my property and it will look ugly - although if I really have to I may be able to plant some other things to provide partial shade - but I'd prefer not to)

https://www.americancamellias.com/education-and-camellia-care/the-camellia-family/growing-camellia-sinensis says they can grow in full sun and would seem a reasonable source - however as with other reputable sources it points out they should be planted in spring or autumn :(
